# Why is my Javascript returning null Record for cities when i select my State in Rails app, using city state gem

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I have been struggling to figure out why I am getting empty array and not getting results back for the cities when state is selected. I follow the blog post [blog post](http://www.learnwithdaniel.com/2015/02/citystate-list-of-countries-cities-and-states-ruby/) and I added a suggestion I read at the end and wonder if that is a more viable way to implement it and how to do so. Can you please give me the best way to solve this?

I am using my ruby gem city-state [city state gem](https://github.com/loureirorg/city-state)

In my Forms I have the following: (adding javascript and form tag in one page for easy read for this forum)

form excerpt

```html
<div class ="form-group">
    <select id="states-of-country" name="project[state]">
        <option value="" selected="">Select Your State</option>
        <% CS.states(:us).each do |key, value| %>
        <option value="&lt;<%= key %>&gt;"><%= value %></option>
        <% end %>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <select id="cities-of-state" name="project[city]">
        <option value="" selected="">Select Your City</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Javascript

```js
$('#states-of-country').change(function () {
    var input_state = $(this);
    var cities_of_state = $("#cities-of-state");

    if ($(this).val() == "") {
        cities_of_state.html("");
    } else {
        $.getJSON('/cities/' + $(this).val(), function (data) {
            // cities_of_state.empty();
            var opt = '<option value="" selected="">Select Your City</option>';
            console.log(data);
            if (data.length == 0) {} else {
                data.forEach(function (i) {
                    opt += '<option value="+ i +">' + i + '</option>';
                    cities_of_state.html(opt);
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Routes.rb

```
get 'cities/:state', to: 'application#cities'
```

When I go into my console and select the state  I get a return of []
console.log(data);  data is Null... can anyone point me to the right direction...>??

Someone on the blog mentioned the following suggestion to make it easier but how do you implement that? [blog post](http://www.learnwithdaniel.com/2015/02/citystate-list-of-countries-cities-and-states-ruby/)

You only need put something like this:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
##your attributes and associations

## your methods
## ..............

    def self.get_countries
        CS.get
    end

    def self.get_states(country_code)
        CS.get country_code.to_sym
    end

    def self.get_cities(state_code)
        CS.get :us state_code.to_sym
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was: "><%= value %>  i needed to remove the < etc that was here previously.

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <select id="states-of-country" name="project[state]">
               <option value="" selected="">Select Your State</option>
               <% CS.states(:us).each do |key, value| %>
               <option value="<%= key %>"><%= value %></option>
               <% end %>
               </select>


</div>
```